# Signed APK network issue - Unsigned apk able to read API but signed apk keeps loading

Tags: android, networking, retrofit, okhttp, signed-apk

I am using retrofit for my application. it is able to read all API data in development mode and even with Build APK. but same version of code not working in signed APK. it just move to onFailRequest. Connectivity check flag shows true that network is connected. I am unsure that it's Android 9 or higher problem. My API server have http://domainname.com only. it doesn't have https. can it be problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by set minify as false. (Build/Edit Buildtype) I read that "if you set this option when code release, some part is removed" so tried with false and it worked.

one other comment was there which tells add  -keep class Responseclass { *; } rule in proguard rules fixed it for me.

but in mycase minify false worked.